# Remove padding below in panel header bootstrap 3.3.4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out why extra padding is being added below my drop down select list in my panel header, does anyone know why it is being added?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dFi4.png)

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Status Connection History</h3>
            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                <select class="form-control" id="statusHistoryDropdown">
                    <option>Past Hour</option>      <!-- increments of 5 minutes    -->
                    <option>Past 12 Hours</option>  <!-- increments of 1 hour       -->
                    <option>Past 3 Days</option>    <!-- increments of 6 hours      -->
                    <option>Past 12 days</option>   <!-- increments of 1 day        -->
                    <option>Past Month</option>     <!-- increments of 2 days       -->
                </select>
            </div>                                  
        </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you talking about right under the "Past Hour" tab?

Comment: If this is what you're talking about, bootstrap has this class .form-group that adds 15px to padding-bottom, so just take it out or overwrite it with .form-group { padding-bottom: 0px; }

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <h3 class="panel-title pull-left">Status Connection History</h3>
            <div class="pull-right">
                <select class="form-control" id="statusHistoryDropdown">
                    <option>Past Hour</option>      <!-- increments of 5 minutes    -->
                    <option>Past 12 Hours</option>  <!-- increments of 1 hour       -->
                    <option>Past 3 Days</option>    <!-- increments of 6 hours      -->
                    <option>Past 12 days</option>   <!-- increments of 1 day        -->
                    <option>Past Month</option>     <!-- increments of 2 days       -->
                </select>
            </div>                                  
        </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        Panel content
    </div>
</div>
```

Remove only form-group class.